Can a character cast and be under the effect of multiple Invoke the Amaranthine spells?
Can a character cast two (or more) Invoke the Amaranthine spells to gain a total of four (or more) dice to use? Or is this not possible due to Combining Magical Effects rule?
Here is the spell:

You call upon the power of an Amaranthine to grant yourself insight into the Great Rhythm that moves all things. When you cast this spell, roll two d20s, and record what you rolled. For each die, choose either attack roll, skill check, or saving throw. You can choose each option multiple times. For the next 24 hours, you may substitute any roll of an ally or enemy you can see within 60 feet with one of the recorded numbers that matches the type of roll you wish to replace (attack roll, skill check, or saving throw). The target still adds any relevant modifiers to this number, but otherwise treat the substituted number as the number they rolled.
To do this, you must spend a reaction to present your holy symbol and invoke the name of the Amaranthine whose energies you called upon. You can do this anytime after the skill check, saving throw or attack has been rolled, but before the outcome of the event has been determined. The spell ends after 24 hours have passed, or when both dice have been expended.

And the relevant rule:

The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap.
For example, if two clerics cast bless on the same target, that character gains the spell's benefit only once; he or she doesn't get to roll two bonus dice.

I'm aware that this spell is from the Humblewood Campaign Setting which is semi-official, partnered content.

Possible duplicate: If you cast a spell with different effect options twice on the same creature, do multiple castings of the spell stack?, Do different effects of the same spell stack? {duplicate}; otherwise related: If you cast Blindness/Deafness as a 3rd level spell, can you target one creature with both effects?, How do multiple castings of Hex affect a creature?...

...Can I cast Bestow Curse twice at greater than 5th level on the same creature?

You have two dice at any given time
As you observe, the rule about Combining Magical Effects (p. 204, PHB) says

The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent

You are casting the same spell more than one time, so its effects won't combine, only the last result applies (or, if you consider a higher roll more potent, the one with the higher rolls - that one is probably up to the DM, as it is not clear if something like a 10 and 17 is more or less potent than something like a 14 and 15).
When the spell says "You can choose each option multiple times" in

roll two d20s, and record what you rolled. For each die, choose either attack roll, skill check, or saving throw. You can choose each option multiple times

what it means is not that you can cast the spell multiple times and accrue the results. The "options" here are what you want to use the rolls on. And there you can choose each option multiple times, so you could choose to use both for an attack roll, or both for a saving throw, for example.
The spell also says:

The spell ends after 24 hours have passed, or when both dice have been expended.

So, while you have two instances of the spell running, the later one is active and the earlier one is suppressed. Once you use up both of the rolls of the second casting, that casting ends, and the first one stops being suppressed, so you then can use its rolls. But you cannot have all four dice available to you at the same time.

This is a well organized and thorough explanation of the rules here. +1.
